# WPF. Is it possible to do ellipse "rectangle bounds" hittest?

Tags: c#, wpf, hittest

Is there possible to make hit test in ellipse bound rectangle, **[like on this image](http://s22.postimg.org/6co1y7vap/image.png)**?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can put them both into a <strike>border</strike> grid and check if it was clicked

XAML:

```
            <Grid MouseDown="Border_MouseDown">
                <Rectangle Width="100"
                           Height="100"
                           Fill="Green" />
                <Ellipse Width="100"
                         Height="100"
                         Fill="Orange" />
            </Grid>
```

Code behind

```
   private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hit it");
        }
```

**EDIT**
Just to make it complete here comes the XAML for green regions only:

```
   <Grid>
            <Rectangle Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Fill="Green"
                       MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" />
            <Ellipse Width="100"
                     Height="100"
                     Fill="Orange" />
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Won't that fire if clicked inside the orange area? He wants it to only fire if in the green area.

Comment: this was not clear for me from the question itself. it says the rectangle bounds...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've added the XAML code to answer also your interpretation of the question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain "He wants it to only fire if in the green area". How do you know? IMO "I need hittest in this green region" means "I need hittest *also* in this green region".

Comment: @Mat Why the Border? You could as well attach the MouseDown handler to the Grid. You wouldn't even need the Rectangle, as you could simply set the Grid's Background.

Comment: @slavka do you like this answer? maybe you want to accept it?

Comment: @Mat, thank you for advices. Yes, your solution is works, but can not be applied in my project (I'm can't create container, that contains other controls). I'm newbie in WPF, and I thought that there is an more easier way, than determine control under cursor by MouseMove event. Thank you, and sorry for my english. :)

Comment: @Mat, as I say, I'm newbie in WPF. In my case, the ellipse background (green area), must be transparent. I thought, that in you approach, if "background" rectangle is transparent, a MouseMove event don't fires. I'm just check this, and I'm wrong. I will do as you say. Thank you again!