# WPF Button ControlTemplate with negative values gives wrong clickbox

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I have a button defined with a `ControlTemplate` like this:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Path Data="M-20,-60L-20,-20 -60,-20 -60,20 -20,20 -20,60 20,60 20,20 60,20 60,-20 20,-20 20,-60z">
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

When I click anywhere but the bottom-right part of the `+` shape, `ButtonBase_OnClick` (and an `ICommand` for that matter) isn't triggered.

[image: Image for clarification]

I eventually plan to use the `Button` in a `Canvas` centered around a certain location, which is why I need the negative values in the `ControlTemplate`.

How can I make it so `ButtonBase_OnClick` triggers while maintaining the same `Shape` in the `ControlTemplate`?

**Edit:**
I tried placing a `Grid` around the `Path` in my `ControlTemplate` as explained in [WPF. Is it possible to do ellipse “rectangle bounds” hittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703613/wpf-is-it-possible-to-do-ellipse-rectangle-bounds-hittest), but that doesn't seem to trigger the `Button`'s `Click` event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF. Is it possible to do ellipse "rectangle bounds" hittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703613/wpf-is-it-possible-to-do-ellipse-rectangle-bounds-hittest)

Comment: @Mat The issue isn't hittesting, it's that the hittest box is misplaced/misaligned, slapping a `Grid` doesn't route the click to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your Path inside a Viewbox

```
<Viewbox Width="50" Height="50">
    <Path here...>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: I don't understand _why_ it works, but it works. I had to change `Width` and `Height` to `60` though. I don't understand why it isn't `120` (the total width/height of the `Path` shape), but that's a small detail.

Comment: With a bit more messing around it seems that replacing the `Viewbox` with a `Canvas` eliminates the need to give it a specific width/height altogether.

Comment: yeah. also, do try to set your data to <Path  Data="M40,0L40,40 0,40 0,80 40,80 40,120 80,120 80,80 120,80 120,40 80,40 80,0z">

and then play with negative margin values on the Button, rather than negative path data values. you might like it more. if it works.(you dont need viewbox/canvas then)